# Problems with FragmentPagerAdapter

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, fragmentpageradapter, android-pageradapter

I'm trying to make a slidescreen with viewpager and fragments so that I can load different layouts per fragment and give each page different functionality.

I followed a [tutorial](http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/implementing-horizontal-view-swiping-using-viewpager-and-fragmentpageradapter-in-android/) to accomplish this.

The error I'm getting when hovering over `public Fragment getItem(int arg0)`: The return type is incompatible with `FragmentPagerAdapter.getItem(int)`

and error #2: The constructor `FragmentPagerAdapter(FragmentManager)` is undefined
--> getting this one when hovering `super(fm);`

```
package com.example.spui;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;

public class MyFragmentPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter{

    final int PAGE_COUNT = 5;

    /** Constructor of the class */
    public MyFragmentPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    /** This method will be invoked when a page is requested to create */
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int arg0) {

        MyFragment myFragment = new MyFragment();
        Bundle data = new Bundle();
        data.putInt("current_page", arg0+1);
        myFragment.setArguments(data);
        return myFragment;
    }

    /** Returns the number of pages */
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return PAGE_COUNT;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You are using the wrong `FragmentManager` import. Use `android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager` instead.

Same problem with `Fragment` -  use `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`

Note: if you are building an API11+ only application and want to use the native Fragments, then you should instead change your `FragmentPagerAdapter` import to `android.support.v13.app.FragmentPagerAdapter`.

Comment: Awesome!! Thanks for the very fast response! That fixed out my errors :D. can you point me in the right direction to use different layouts for every page? Or should I make a new question for this, Because still trying to figure that one out

Btw. "You can accept an answer in 3 minutes"

Comment: getItem can return any Fragment you want - if you want totally different functionality on each page, just return a different Fragment  based on the page number.

Comment: Do I do this in MyFragment or in MyFragmentPagerAdapter? I update the question with a new class so you can see 'MyFragment'

What is difference between support v13 and v4?

Comment: Support v13 uses the android.app versions of Fragment, FragmentManager, etc. that were introduced in API v11, rather than the android.support.v4.app versions which are available for all API levels.

Comment: And additional questions/issues should be asked as separate StackOverflow questions.

Comment: Thanks for the information about the versions.

Ow okay, I'll ask a new question then and I'll delete the added question. Thanks for your help @ianhanniballake