# Alternate to FragmentPagerAdapter

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-tabs, fragmentpageradapter

I have developer the whole my project with

```
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
```

and using Tabs with ActionBar. Now i need to swipe between tabs. I have seen many examples even the sample project of Android, but all imports they used are with `support.v4.app` and hence they can use `FragmentPagerAdapter`. My min sdk is 14. Is there any way to use `FragmentPagerAdapter` in my project or any alternative for `Viewpager`. I have gone through some of related post like : 
[FragmentPagerAdapter Exists Only In Android.Support.V4.App (and not Android.App)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13501424/fragmentpageradapter-exists-only-in-android-support-v4-app-and-not-android-app)

[Problems with FragmentPagerAdapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15414535/problems-with-fragmentpageradapter)

When i import `android.support.v13.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.`, it couldn't be resolved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could copy [the source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/refs/heads/master/v13/java/android/support/v13/app/FragmentPagerAdapter.java) and make necessary changes to use the non-support versions of the classes referenced in FragmentPagerAdapter (like `Fragment`). It should be enough to just change the imports to the non-support versions of those classes.

Comment: Thnx, I imported the whole file.

Answer (score 0):

Import the library android-sdk\extras\android\support\v13\android-support-v13.jar
There is everything you need.